# Proving that, if $y_1\geq y_2$ at some interval $[x_0, x_1]$, there exists a point where $y_1'>y_2'$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, maxima-minima

I am working on an exercise on ODE and I need the following lemma to solve it. 
*Lemma:* Let two functions $y_1, y_2$: $[x_0, x_1]\to\mathbb{R}$, such that $y_1(x_0) = y_2(x_0)$ and $y_1(x_1) = y_2(x_1)$. Moreover $y_1(x)>y_2(x) \; \forall x\in (x_0, x_1)$. Prove that there exists some point $z\in(x_0,x_1)$, for which $y_1'(z) > y_2'(z)$.

It is geometrically obvious, as every point near enough $x_0$ satisfies the condition, but I couldn't prove it formally. I tried working with local maximums and minimums, but I think there is a more obvious way than considering all options for $max$ and $min$.

EDIT: $y_1, y_2$ are differentiable in $(x_0, x_1)$.

Comment: You never state that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are continuous or differential at all.  If not this is not true. If they are use the mean value theorem.

Comment: Ah, they are solutions to a differential equation of type $y'=f(x,y), where f is continuous$, therefore they are differentiable in there. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both $y_1, y_2$ are continuously differentiable:

Let $f(x) = y_1(x)-y_2(x)$. Then $f(x_0)=f(x_1)=0$ and $f(x) > 0$ for all $x\in(x_0, x_1)$.

Let $x_2 \in(x_0, x_1)$. Then by Mean Value Theorem:

$$\exists z \in (x_0,x_2): f'(z)=\frac {f(x_2)-f(x_0)}{x_2-x_0}=\frac {f(x_2)}{x_2-x_0}>0$$

Hence $y_1'(z)-y_2'(z)>0$.

As a bonus you can also prove there are points where $y_1'(\xi)=y_2'(\xi)$, and even $y_1'(\xi)<y_2'(\xi)$.

Comment: Seems correct. Thanks). I didn't come up with the function $f$. I used the Mean Value theorem, but separately for both functions and all I got was $\exists z_1, z_2 \in (x_0, x_1)$, so that $y_1'(z_1) = y_2'(z_2)$, but that did not help.